# Error 404 on CNAME forward

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, godaddy

In my DNS manager, GoDaddy I made some A Record that points to *.mirror for my domain

[image]

Now when I access URL 123.mirror.mydomain.com from the browser I can see that my app is loaded, and its all OK.

My problem now is when doing a CNAME point to the URL above on another domain DNS manager like this:

[image]

Accessing 123.otherdomain.com which I expect to "forward to" 123.mirror.mydomain.com I only get this 404 error:

[image]

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

When you try to access a domain with a CNAME record in your browser, two things of significance to this question happen.

1: The browser determines the IP address to connect to. This means that the browser will follow the CNAME record of `123.otherhost.com` to the IP of `123.mirror.yourdomain.com`

2: The browser will request the page with a host header that is equal to the domain entered in the address bar. This means the browser will request the page from `http://123.otherdomain.com`

It sounds like you may want to alias 123.otherdomain.com and 123.mirror.yourdomain.com in the same virtual host.

Comment: You mean its not possible to achieve this?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to be able for 'anydomain.com' CNAME www to point to my app subdomain

Comment: Yes, but you would need to configure your app.subdomain to also include the alias anydomain.com or *.anydomain.com, etc.

Comment: Do you mean that in GoDaddy console for my domain, say mydomain.com I will need to add all the domains I need to point to it, like abc.com, xyz.com or anydomain.com?

Comment: How can I add alias of anydomain.com on my control panel for mydomain.com

Comment: You need to configure the alias on your **web server**, so it accepts both it's main domain name and the new `123.otherhost.com`.